# Getting None from form in Django

Tags: python, django

In one of my django I have a form that creates a new product in the database:

views.py

```
class ProductCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = "products/my-products.html"
    model = Product
    form_class = AddNewProductForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/my-products/")
```

forms.py

```
AVAILABLE_YEAR_CHOICES = list(range(1960, 2051))

class AddNewProductForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["date", "time", "title", "desrciption"]
        widgets = {'date': forms.SelectDateWidget(years=AVAILABLE_YEAR_CHOICES)}
```

Using the above, everything works perfectly.

I wanted to add the current date and time to the date and time widgets, so I tried the following:

forms.py

```
class AddNewProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateField(label='date', initial=datetime.date.today(),
                           widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=AVAILABLE_YEAR_CHOICES))
    time = forms.TimeField(label="time", initial=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"))
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["title", "desrciption"]
```

When I use this, I get an error that the date field is None.

I am not sure why this is really happening. Using just the fields in Meta works, but doing something custom gives None.

Comment: In your example initial data always will be the same (date and time of django launch). Pass only method like `initial=datetime.date.today` and django will call it before form rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to specify the fields in the second example:

```
class AddNewProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateField(label='date', initial=datetime.date.today(),
                           widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=AVAILABLE_YEAR_CHOICES))
    time = forms.TimeField(label="time", initial=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"))
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["title", "description", "date", "time"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_initial_for_field` method for it

```
AVAILABLE_YEAR_CHOICES = list(range(1960, 2051))

class AddNewProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["date", "time", "title", "desrciption"]
        widgets = {'date': forms.SelectDateWidget(years=AVAILABLE_YEAR_CHOICES)}

    def get_initial_for_field(self, field, field_name):
        if field_name == 'date':
            return datetime.date.today()
        if field_name == 'time':
            return datetime.datetime.now().time()
        return super().get_initial_for_field(field, field_name)
```

Also instead of `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")` do next `datetime.datetime.now().time()`